# Defining discrete set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

$\mathcal{S}$ is a set with discrete elements. Is it a good practice to write $|\mathcal{S}| < \infty$ in order to say $\mathcal{S}$ is discrete? This is  not a common notation, but is short and effective in my view.

Note: it is also not of infinitely many elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't actually make sense. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956153/what-is-a-discrete-set-exactly) for more information about why a set with discrete elements isn't an actual thing.

$|\mathcal S|<\infty$ means that $\mathcal S$ is finite, and tells you nothing about the topology on the set. It's perfectly fine to use this notation to denote finiteness.